# DAX formula to create a date table

Tags: sql, powerbi

In one of the interview today, interviewer has sent the below SQL query and asked me to write a DAX formula in Power BI.

```
create table dim_date (datekey int)
declare @x int = 0
while @x <=365
begin
insert into dim_date values (dateadd(getdate(),@x))
set @x=@x+1
end
```

Please help me to write DAX for this SQL query.

Comment: "Solve my interview question" isn't a good question for this site. Please try it yourself.  if you have tried it and will get a concrete problem on the way to your solution, we are glad to help on the specific topic.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion finder2. Will follow the same in the future doubts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CALENDAR](https://dax.guide/calendar/) and [TODAY](https://dax.guide/today/) DAX functions to create a [calculated table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-calculated-tables) like this:

```
dim_date = CALENDAR(TODAY(), TODAY() + 365)
```

Comment: It is giving me a table, is it the right answer for the SQL query that have provided earlier? Because i did not know how to answer that question in the interview

Comment: This DAX code will create a table and fill it with values (as the SQL code does). Is it correct or not depends on the expectations of the interviewer and your answers on the supplementary questions around this.